# Soundcloud application connect via Facebook connect can't run the script for call back

Tags: facebook, soundcloud

It seems like Soundcloud's problem. If you have an application on Soundcloud and your members try to connect to this application they will see two options:

1. Sign in with your Soundcloud account.
2. Sign in with your Facebook account.

The problem is with Facebook connect.

Normally if you click on the Facebook connect button it has to open a popup, then you accept and login. But the Soundcloud Facebook connect button doesn't open any popup window and that's why it cannot run the javascript code which is trying to reach window.opener scope.

Here is Firebug error:

```
window.opener is null
popup_callback.html?returnTo=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.giggem.com%2Fprofile%3Fcode%3D4a360828894b6fc6d4029fa3e9fbf108()popup_...9fbf108 (line 9)
[Break On This Error]   

...ar params    = window.opener.$.helpers.urlencodedToObject(window.location.search...
```

I couldn't find any page to report this in Soundcloud's website that's why I wrote it here.

How do I establish a connection via Soundcloud/Facebook?

Note : Using Firefox 13.0.1 under Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Isn't this a support question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a user asking for help using Soundcloud's Facebook Login feature

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the same problem and it's been like this for months. Here is a screenshot to help identify what the issue is:

http://d.pr/i/NFf
[image: SO11360202 example]

Looking into the code, it seems this is the offending script:

```
var params    = window.opener.$.helpers.urlencodedToObject(window.location.search)
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug on our side. The FB connect flow is assuming that you're using a popup window to connect w/ soundcloud. I'll report back here when we've got it sorted out.

Comment: I've had to completely remove the login as Soundcloud option from my site now. Actually, I've had to completely remove that and then make all uploads go into a single premium account. I guess that's good for you guys, but not so good for my clients. Please update us when you've rectified the situation. Thanks!