# Soundcloud: blank page with popup_callback.html when trying to auth using Facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I'm going through the OAuth2 flow with my application. The application seems to correctly request https://soundcloud.com/connect, with "Allow 'app name' access to your Soundcloud account?". However, if I then try to authenticate using Facebook on this screen, a new, empty page loads with the url:

```
https://soundcloud.com/popup_callback.html?returnTo=http%3A%2F%2Fapp-url.com...
```

After that, nothing happens. If I re-request the connect page with my app, I have been successfully logged into Soundcloud, and can simply click the "Connect" button.

This was working about a week ago.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360202/soundcloud-application-connect-via-facebook-connect-cant-run-the-script-for-call

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: No I didn't, sorry. Please post back here if you figure it out.

Comment: This appears to be a bug on our side. The FB connect flow is assuming that you're using a popup window to connect w/ soundcloud. I'll report back here when we've got it sorted out.

Comment: This has been resolved. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @PaulOsman could you please confirm that the issue has been resolved? I'm still having the same issue. When I'm redirected to https://soundcloud.com/popup_callback.html I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of null "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment from Paul Osman. This was a bug on the Soundcloud side and has been fixed.