# Soundcloud popup_callback.html not redirected to callback url after Facebook login

Tags: api, authentication, callback, soundcloud

my first post after years of reading :P
I think that are some problem with the page of soundcloud https://soundcloud.com/popup_callback.html

My app uses the soundcloud api and work fine, but when my users try to connect with facebook and they are go from facebook to 
https://soundcloud.com/popup_callback.html?returnTo=CALLBACK_URL
but it is not redirected to the callback url, only show a empty page.

Users need login in soundcloud in other window before to make login in my app.
Can be a problem my callback url? "http://domain.com/callback/"

I try it in ff, opera and chrome and diferents at S.O.

Comment: Seconded - pretty aggravating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the SoundCloud API (see [Soundcloud: blank page with popup_callback.html when trying to auth using Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544193/soundcloud-blank-page-with-popup-callback-html-when-trying-to-auth-using-facebo))

I was able to work around this by including `display=popup` in the querystring when redirecting to SoundCloud's OAuth2 authorization endpoint: `https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=[my_client_id]&redirect_uri=[my_redirect_uri]&response_type=code&display=popup`. This will force the mobile optimized display to show up, but fixes the Facebook login issue.

Note that I'm not actually opening a popup window, I'm just including this param when doing a client-side redirect using `window.location='https://soundcloud.com/connect?...&display=popup'`